# how to use substring with a delimiter

Tags: oracle, substring

Employee_M

```
City        Emp_Num_ID
Cleveland   2164445437/FTTD/JAMES, TYLER/139561151
Tokyo       1261120379/FTTD/BOYD, ADAMS/14468140  
Marakech    4049838896/FTTD/SMITH, TULY E/13956144
Houston     7980151429/FTTD/NEARY, HARTMAN/14215411
```

I'm trying to extract all digits after the third / with substring

```
select substr(Emp_Num_ID,/,10) as Emp_ID 
from Employee_M
```

sometimes we can have between 4 to 10 charterers after the third / so I chose 10 for the length.

any idea how to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

- You can use the `instr` function to get the position of the last `/`
  `-1` means you are looking from the end of the string.
- Then you add 1, so your start position will be the first character after `/`.
- You do not need the third parameter in `substr` if you need the substring until the end of the string.

  `select substr(Emp_Num_ID,instr(Emp_Num_ID,'/',-1)+1) as Emp_ID from Employee_M`

Comment: thanks it worked like a charm, but when I try to compare that with another field I'm getting an error. 
`select substr(Emp_Num_ID,instr(Emp_Num_ID,'/',-1)+1) as Emp_ID from Employee_M where substr(Emp_Num_ID,instr(Emp_Num_ID,'/',-1)+1)=City` I'm getting  "ORA-01722: invalid number" anyway that I can use this against another field

Comment: i have just tested and it works  =>[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2e1356670221a328295fa1b6404ff078).

Comment: [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=49acfa743f017b1a5866af040c2bd170) is also an exmple what could cause the invalid number exception. you have to check your data